# How to Roll Back (Undo) a Deployment in GCP with Google Cloud Deployment Manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-deployment-manager

Google Cloud Deployment Manager is an excellent IaC tool with three core features.

- create - Create a deployment.
- delete - Delete a deployment.
- update - Update a deployment based on a provided config file.

**Reference:**

1. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deployment-manager

Can we roll back/undo a deployment using Google Cloud Deployment Manager?

Comment: `delete` deletes a deployment including its resources.

Comment: If you're new to Deployment Manager, I encourage you to consider [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/).  Deployment Manager is Google-specific, closed-source and proprietary. Terraform has an open-source Google Cloud [provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs) that's developed by Google, is [documented](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform#docs) by Google, appears to have more momentum, doesn't lock you into Google (Cloud) and (importantly) enables you to manage resources that Google doesn't include with Deployment Manager.

Comment: To answer your question if we can roll back/undo a deployment using Google Cloud Deployment Manager the answer is No, In addition to @DazWilkin have explained that Google Cloud Deployment Manager is an infrastructure deployment service that automates the creation and management of Google Cloud resources.

Comment: I was unclear, unless I'm missing a nuance,.`delete` is `undo`. Corollary: what would you like to achieve with "undo" that isn't achieved by "delete"?